# Pipe grep output to xargs

Tags: grep, xargs

I'm trying to filter the output of `git ls-files` for some reporting commands, and then pipe that output to `xargs`. I was originally using `-z` on `git ls-files` which worked fine, but now that I'm piping to grep, I need to restore that functionality.

Trying the grep version `-Z` isn't doing anything to the actual output.

```
git ls-files | grep -Z -e={\*.js,\*.html}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `-Z` option to grep only seems to apply to the filenames that contained the matched content not the content of the matching lines. That seems rather strange to me but that appears to be how it works.

You don't actually need `grep` here though (you didn't need the `*` in the original either it didn't add anything of value).

`git ls-files` takes a pattern to match against the filenames.

So you want to use this command here.

```
git ls-files -z -- '*.js' '*.html'
```

Comment: Agreed, I thought it was weird it referred specifically to filenames. This solves the issue though - I kept looking at the ls-files docs expecting a specific argument for file patterns.

Comment: Although, I do know that ls-files cannot *exclude* files that are tracked in the repo - and it my case it's likely easier to exclude files that specifically list includes.

Comment: I don't think I followed that exclude comment. `ls-files` can show untracked files. It can show only ignored files. It also has exclude pattern support.

Comment: It only excludes untracked files though, if the files are already tracked in the repo the `--exclude` argument doesn't apply. I'm writing these commands to run a quick count of lines written by author. I originally wanted to exclude a list of binary files only, rather than whitelist specific files - but I think both ways are actually equally verbose so it's not an issue.

Comment: Ah, true, the exclusion is only for untracked files